# android spinner width problem?

Tags: android, spinner

i have created following layout.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TableRow>


<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Post As" />


<Spinner 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ddlPostAs"
        />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Expires In" />

<Spinner 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ddlExpiryOn"

        />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

in which android spinner changes its width according to the data.
i want to stop it.

can any one guide me how to achieve this?

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By fixing the width according to the width of screen.

```
 DisplayMetrics d = new DisplayMetrics(); 
 getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(d); 
 int wdt = d.widthPixels;
 ddlpostas.getLayoutParams().width = wdt - 120;
 ddlexpiryon.getLayoutParams().width = wdt - 120;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "android:weightSum"  on your `<TableRow>` to adjust the width fixed on the screen.

Example :

```
<TableRow android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Post As"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ddlPostAs"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </TableRow>
```

By this code your spinner width will be set as half the width of your TableRow.

Change the values of android:weightSum and android:layout_weight as per your requirement.